# How to create an error message box for an empty text box: VB 2010 Express

Tags: vb.net

I am taking VB this semester, and while it is not required for this particular assignment, I am curious how I can create a MessageBox error if a text box is left empty.

We just covered using the Try/Catch statement, and I have successfully created MessageBoxes for text boxes whose text is only numeric.  For example, a user must enter a name, and two numeric amounts.  I am trying to create an error if the Name text box is left empty, stop the program from calculating the two amounts and return the insertion point to the Name text box.

Is there an easier way to do this?  The If/Then statement I currently have does not stop the program from calculating (I am just starting out so go easy on me):

```
Private Sub CalculateButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalculateButton.Click    
    'Declare Variables
    Dim SellingPrice, CostValue, Commission As Decimal

    'Test to see if a name was provided the NameTextBox
    If NameTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Salesperson's name", "No entry",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        With NameTextBox
            .Focus()
            .SelectAll()
        End With
    End If

    'Test if Numerical data was entered for SellingPriceTextBox
    Try
        'Convert Selling Price 
        SellingPrice = Decimal.Parse(SellingPriceTextBox.Text)

        'Test if Numerical data was entered for CostValueTextBox
        Try
            'Convert Cost Value 
            CostValue = Decimal.Parse(CostValueTextBox.Text)

            'Calculate the Commission earned 
            Commission = Decimal.Round(COMMISSION_RATE * (SellingPrice - CostValue), 2)

            'Format and display results
            TotalCommissionLabel.Text = Commission.ToString("C")

        Catch CostValueException As FormatException
            'Handle a Cost Value exception
            MessageBox.Show("Value must be a numeric value.", "Invalid Input",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            With CostValueTextBox
                .Focus()
                .SelectAll()
            End With
        End Try
    Catch SellingPriceException As FormatException
        'Handle a Selling Price exception
        MessageBox.Show("Price must be a numeric value.", "Invalid Input",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        With SellingPriceTextBox
            .Focus()
            .SelectAll()
        End With
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    If NameTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Salesperson's name", "No entry",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        With NameTextBox
            .Focus()
            .SelectAll()
        End With
        Exit Sub                    ' tell it to skip the rest
    End If
```

I'd split that part off into a Function to determine if the data is valid, and only invoke the Calculations if it is valid.  Something like:

```
Private Sub CalculateButton_Click...
    If DataComplete() Then
        DoCalcs()
    End If
```

You are likely to want to perform those calcs elsewhere so it would be nice to be able to invoke them from other than a click event.  `DataComplete` could be as little as:

```
Return NameTextBox.Text.Length > 0
```

Later it would likely need to see if such a sales person exists etc

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Just a little massaging of your code should get it working.

```
If NameTextBox.Text = "" Then
   MessageBox.Show(...)
Else
   Do Calculation...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `If-Else` logic, like this:

```
Private Sub CalculateButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalculateButton.Click
    'Test to see if a name was provided the NameTextBox
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(NameTextBox.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Salesperson's name", "No entry",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        With NameTextBox
            .Focus()
            .SelectAll()
        End With
    Else
        'Declare Variables
        Dim SellingPrice, CostValue, Commission As Decimal

        'Test if Numerical data was entered for SellingPriceTextBox
        Try
            'Convert Selling Price 
            SellingPrice = Decimal.Parse(SellingPriceTextBox.Text)

            'Test if Numerical data was entered for CostValueTextBox
            Try
                'Convert Cost Value 
                CostValue = Decimal.Parse(CostValueTextBox.Text)

                'Calculate the Commission earned 
                Commission = Decimal.Round(COMMISSION_RATE * (SellingPrice - CostValue), 2)

                'Format and display results
                TotalCommissionLabel.Text = Commission.ToString("C")

            Catch CostValueException As FormatException
                'Handle a Cost Value exception
                MessageBox.Show("Value must be a numeric value.", "Invalid Input",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                With CostValueTextBox
                    .Focus()
                    .SelectAll()
                End With
            End Try
        Catch SellingPriceException As FormatException
            'Handle a Selling Price exception
            MessageBox.Show("Price must be a numeric value.", "Invalid Input",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            With SellingPriceTextBox
                .Focus()
                .SelectAll()
            End With
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

This guarantees either the error message is shown to the user indicating that they need to enter a salesperson's name or the calculation logic is performed, but not both.

Note: I also added the use of the `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` method to test whether or not the textbox had a value. I find that syntax cleaner than checking for an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
If lblPriceTotalClothes.Text & lblPriceTotalElectronics.Text & lblPriceTotalGames.Text & lblPriceTotalJewellry.Text = Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please choose something to buy!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        lblSubtotalPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(0)
        lblTotalCostPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(0)
        lbltaxesPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(0)
        Return
Else
        lblSubtotalPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(subTotalPrice)
        taxes = FormatCurrency(subTotalPrice * 0.13)
        lblTotalCostPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(subTotalPrice + taxes)
        lbltaxesPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(taxes)
        MessageBox.Show("Thank you for shopping!", "Thank You", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
 End If
```